# How Show a Form on top of other?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a first Form that is always displayed of way:

1. Maximized and as content a printscreen of atual screen
2. Always on top
3. without borders

and now I want show a second Form on top this first Form, but I haven't success until this moment, in another words, this second Form don't is displayed on top. So how I can do it? All suggestions here are welcome.

**Here is how I'm making for show the first Form:**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each s As Screen In Screen.AllScreens
            Dim Locker As New Form2(s, 0.3)
            Locker.Show()
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

**=========================================================================**

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Sub New(ByVal scrn As Screen, ByVal FrmOpacity As Double)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        Me.Bounds = scrn.Bounds
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.Opacity = FrmOpacity
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None
        CaptureScreen(scrn)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CaptureScreen(ByVal s As Screen)
        Using ScreenImg As New Bitmap(s.Bounds.Width, s.Bounds.Height)
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenImg)
                g.CopyFromScreen(s.Bounds.Location, Point.Empty, ScreenImg.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
            End Using
            Me.BackgroundImage = New Bitmap(ScreenImg)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why not set Form1 "TopMost = False" when you display Form2?

Comment: Check out the [MDI pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply set the [Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) of the form2 to be form1

```
Public Class Form1

    .....

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each s As Screen In Screen.AllScreens
            Dim Locker As New Form2(s, 0.3)
            Locker.Show(Me)
        Next
    End Sub

    .....

End Class
```

Passing the instance of Form1 to the [Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx) method of Form2 will set the passed instance of the Form1 as the `Owner` of all the `Locker` forms that your create in your loop. In this way the Form2 instance will be always above the Form1 instance. Of course, you could remove the setting of the `TopMost=True` property that could be assigned only to one form at a time (Only one form could be the TopMost)

From MSDN on Owner form property

> When a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden with the
>   owner form. For example, consider a form named Form2 that is owned by
>   a form named Form1. If Form1 is closed or minimized, Form2 is also
>   closed or hidden. Owned forms are also never displayed behind their
>   owner form. You can use owned forms for windows such as find and
>   replace windows, which should not disappear when the owner form is
>   selected. To determine the forms that are owned by a parent form, use
>   the OwnedForms property.

Comment: in my case, the Form2 class is my Form1, and I want show a other Form ("Form2") over Form1. But Form1 (the Locker Form) not allow do this. These commands are sent from my Server Application to Client Application, "Open Form Locker" and after "Open Form2".

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Modal Dialog.  I don't know vb.Net, but in C# .Net if you say

```
NameOfFormThatShouldBeOnTop.Show();
```

The form will just show but not necessarily be on top.  However, if you go

```
NameOfFormThatShouldBeOnTop.ShowDialog();
```

It will be forced on top.  From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2), it looks like doing this in vb is pretty similar.  I would guess it would be something like

```
NameOfFormThatShouldBeOnTop.ShowDialog()
```

If I got that syntax wrong, feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to load a Sub after the LOAD or SHOWN events, that will contain the below code:

```
private sub LeaveMeAtTop()
     Me.Topmost = True
     Me.TopLevel = true
     Me.Activate()
     Me.ResizeRedraw() = true
     Me.ResumeLayout()
     Me.Focus()
end sub
```

It will force the form to be displayed at top of all